# jquery animate text color opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, opacity

I have just started working on a site and decided to use jquery's animate function to slide the header down the page. As it slides down a div is shown with text. The text show's up grey and not black. I have tried using css and no luck.

Can anyone help and explain what I need to do? I know it has to do with the opacity.

I want to display a div over the header div that is not affected by its opacity.

index.php:

```
<center><div class="table"  id="header">
  <div class="row" id="body">grey</div>
</div></center>
```

Main.css:

```
html, body, div, span, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a, img, form, table, tr, td {margin:0; padding:0; border:0; vertical-align:baseline; text-align:center;}
html, body {background-color:#EEEEEE;}
#header {min-width:80%; background-color:white;}
.table {display: table;}
.row {display: table-row;}
.cell {display: table-cell;}
```

index.css:

```
#header {height:500px; background:grey;}
```

index.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#header").hide();
$("#body").hide();

$( "#header" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
  $("#body").show();
});
```

});

Comment: do u have a fiddle of this? anyway... try setting the div to position absolute, it is not affect by the opacity of the over div.

Comment: Not sure what a fiddle is. Should I set the parent div to absolute or the child? If I set the child to absolute should I position the parent?

Comment: A 'fiddle' (properly a proper noun: 'Fiddle') refers to a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live demo.

Comment: I'm just using jquery and my own js file

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `opacity: 0.25` to `opacity: 1.0`

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/maximgladkov/TRqaZ/

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="background"></div>
    <div id="text">Sample text</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}

#background {
    background: grey;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#text {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#text').animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: I want the opacity. Is it possible to keep the opacity while doing this?

Comment: Right now I have it set so it starts grey and transitions with the opacity but I don't know how to make it so the opacity doesn't affect the child div

Comment: It's impossible. You need to add additional child with style: `position: absolute` and background color o your choose. After that you should animate this child's opacity.

Comment: Thanks. I want to try what you said and see what results that would give me but I'm having a hard time following what you said. Could you give me instructions on how I can try this, please?

Comment: Didn't help. Thanks for the help anyway! If what I'm trying is impossible I gotta look for an alternative path

Comment: Have you looked at my example? Isn't an expected behavior?

Comment: I didn't look at it before trying.. I was tryin to make the parent div opacity not affect the child div

Comment: Please, take a look. It should exactly that you are expecting.